# Как в гугл таблице получить курс доллара на определенную дату по курсу ЦБ, подставив в качестве аргумента ячейку с датой

Tags: google-spreadsheet

В гугл таблице имеется ячейка A1 с содержимом "01/01/2020", требуется в ячейке B1 получить курс на эту дату, если вручную ввести дату в формулу, но все нормально

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=01/01/2020"; "//ValCurs/Valute[CharCode=""USD""]/Value")
```

нашел такие варианты, но они не работают:

```
=IMPORTXML(("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=";A1); "//ValCurs/Valute[CharCode=""USD""]/Value")"))

=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=";A1); "//ValCurs/Valute[CharCode=""USD""]/Value")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req="&A1; "//ValCurs/Valute[CharCode=""USD""]/Value")
```

Формат A1 - Обычный текст.

Comment: Спасибо, из-за формата не работало до этого

Comment: Рад, что ваша проблема решена.

Comment: Дополню ответ, если в вашем документе локаль не Русская, то значения будут не правильные, проблема будет в запятой в значении курса. Потому нужно уточнить формулу проставив там locale, в случае с ЦБ нужна RU:

=IMPORTXML("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req="&A1; "//ValCurs/Valute[CharCode=""USD""]/Value", "RU")

Также если вам нужен запрос на последнюю известную дату с двумя цифрами после запятой в значении валюты то вы можете использовать этот:

=TEXT(IMPORTXML("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp", "//ValCurs/Valute[CharCode=""USD""]/Value", "RU"), "#.##")

Answer (score 0):

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req="&IF(DAY(C4)>9; DAY(C4); "0"&DAY(C4))&"/"&IF(MONTH(C4)>9; MONTH(C4); "0"&MONTH(C4))&"/"&YEAR(C4); "//ValCurs/Valute[CharCode=""USD""]/Value")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req="&ТЕКСТ(A1;"DD/MM/YYYY"); "//ValCurs/Valute[CharCode=""USD""]/Value")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]